# How to find $Z(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle a,b : a^{8}=b^2=1, bab=a^{5}\rangle$ and $A=\{I_{G},\phi_{a}\}.$

> I can't understand why $\phi_{a}(b)=a^{4}b$.

Let $X=G/A=\{\{1\},\{a\},\dots,\{a^{7}\},\{b,a^{4}b\},\{ab,a^{5}b\},\{a^{2}b,a^{6}b\},\{a^{3}b,a^{7}b\}\}$
and consider the following: $$\{a^{\alpha}\}\ast\{a^{\beta}b\}=[\{a^{{\alpha} +{\beta}}b,a^{{\alpha }+{\beta} +{ 4}}b\},\{a^{{\alpha} +{\beta}}b\,a^{{\alpha }+{\beta} +{ 4}}b\}]$$
and
$$\{a^{\beta}b,a^{\beta+4}b\}\ast\{a^{\alpha }\}=[\{a^{{{5}{\alpha}} +{\beta}}b,a^{{{5}{\alpha}} +{\beta}+{4}}\},\{a^{{{5}{\alpha}} +{\beta}}b,a^{{{5}{\alpha}} +{\beta}+{4}}\}].$$

> Question: How to find $Z(X)$?

Comment: Please explain your notation when it is not standard.

Comment: $Q_{1}$:i dont know                                         $Q_{2}$:no                                                                   $Q_{3}$:which notaion? pleaee tell so i explain u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $bab=a^5$ you get (by multiplying to the left by $a^{-1}$) that $a^{-1}bab=a^4$ and using $b^2=1$ and multiplying to the right by $b$ you get $a^{-1}ba=a^4b$, that is, $\phi_a(b)=a^{-1}ba=a^4b$.